# Blocked WiFi - Lenovo IdeaPad y570 Arch Linux

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, arch-linux, lenovo-laptop

I have a problem with setting up my wireless connection.
Recently I have installed Arch Linux on my machine without setting wireless at all (I used wired connection). Now, I want to configure my wireless connection but I when I try to turn it on:

```
idea-arch ~ # ip link set wlp8s0 up
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not possible due to RF-kill
```

Here are some outputs:

```
idea-arch ~ # ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp7s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT   qlen 1000
link/ether dc:0e:a1:7d:af:5f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlp8s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
link/ether 74:e5:0b:cc:80:ba brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

idea-arch ~ # rfkill list all
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
5: phy3: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

I have tried using Fn+F5 but it leads only to soft block. Also, I have tried `rmmod iwlwifi` and `rmmod iwldvm` while I have my hardware switch on laptot off. Then I turn it on my laptot and did `modprobe iwlwifi` and `modprobe iwldvm`  - still no success.

I am using Lenovo Ideapad Y570, shiped with Windows 7 but reinstall to only Arch Linux machine. My network adapters according to `lspci|grep -i net` are:

```
idea-arch ~ # lspci|grep -i net
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57781 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 10)
08:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]
```

I am sure that hardware switch is on. What else can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was afraid, here is the solution. I had to install Win 7 again, install Lenovo Energy Management Utility, turn on wifi on windows and then, Hard Block disapear. Now it works like a charm. Hope this helps someone with same laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Install the packages:

`#pacman -S iw wpa_supplicant wpa_actiond dialog`

After finishing, you can connect to the network with wifi-menu `interface_name` (where  `interface_name` is the interface of your wireless chipset).

```
# wifi-menu interface_name
```

Comment: I tried this but this is output:`idea-arch ~ :( # wifi-menu wlp8s0
Scanning for networks... failed
No networks found`

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem on a old Toshiba laptop and Archlinux (no way to disable the "Hard block").

I never managed to make it work...until I installed Gnome Shell/Gnome 3 (and of course the networkmanager demon). In the network settings I was able to enable it, and it works. I didn't search why the gnome thing worked and the other tool didn't, as it solved my problem !

So maybe you can try that.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. I have installed Gnome3 and from GUI I tried to set the wifi on but, it says that hardware switch is off :( I have read that this laptot wifi is somehow linked to windows Lenovo app so maybe the thing that I have the wifi turned off during uninstalling win and installing arch made this hardware switch off. I may try reinstalling windows again, turn on wifi and then install arch again..